# Why is this contact always coming up as Nil / null, even when I set it or add emails?

Tags: xcode, abaddressbook

In iOS 6, this code always gives me `Nil` for the second `NSLog`, however the first always gives the correct Composite Name.  Hence I know I have access to the addressbook, if I change the name in `addressbook`, the code logs the correct Composite Name.  No matter how many emails I put in, the contact `ABMultiValueGetCount` is always `Nil`.  Why is this?

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[addressBookArray objectAtIndex:x];

NSLog(@"%@ -", ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
NSLog(@"%ld -", ABMultiValueGetCount(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it ... looks like some sort of managedObjectContext condition I should have anticipated ...

In one View Controller I did this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
addressBookArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
// Prsented info on the user name, but not on the Emails
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

In the second view controller I passed addressBookArray to try and save on some cycles then did this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
// Successfully accessed name properties (suspect they were chached some where ?
// Unsuccsfully accessed email properties (they have never been accessed so no chache and I get Null
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

The fix ... In the secondviewController repeat:

```
addressBookArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Bingo problem solved !!

Answer (score 1):

Please check following links. Those may solve your problem. In ios6 apple have changed the permission of address book.

[App crashed in iOS 6 when user changes Contacts access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810638/app-crashed-in-ios-6-when-user-changes-contacts-access-permissions)

[iOS 6 Address Book not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517394/ios-6-address-book-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this -  I'll check, but I'm 100% positive I have access to the AB ! Why would the ABRecordCopyCompositeName  work if I didn't have access ?

Comment: ran ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion with a postiive result and still can't see emails :(