# App not asking for Contact access permission on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, abaddressbook

I am using below Code, My application don't ask permission on iOS 6 while on iOS 7 and above version it ask for Contact permission access. On iOS 6 it doesn't show app in privacy setting as well. I have read some other thread but not found any solutions.

[App crashed in iOS 6 when user changes Contacts access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810638/app-crashed-in-ios-6-when-user-changes-contacts-access-permissions)

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {

    __block CDNDeviceContact *controller = self;

    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef,
                                                 ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                                                     if (granted)
                                                         [controller loadContacts];
                                                     else [controller doAlertForContact];
                                                 });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        [self loadContacts];
    } else {
        [controller doAlertForContact];
    }
    if (addressBookRef)  CFRelease(addressBookRef);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user has previously been presented with the request to get permission, it will not show again. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion),

> The user is only asked for permission the first time you request access. Later calls use the permission granted by the user.

If testing in the simulator, I recommend that you go to iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings so that you are able to simulate the event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO` and you also don't need to create an `ABAddressBookRef`.

For me, this is works like a charm:

```
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()) {
        case kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:{
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                self.addContactButton.enabled = granted;
                if (granted) {
                    // granted
                } else {
                    // User denied access
                }});
        } break;

        case kABAuthorizationStatusDenied: break;
        case kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: from where it comes self.addressbook without creating an addressBookRef.