# iOS - My application doesn't appear in Settings>Privacy>Contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, addressbook, privacy

Although my application tends to access the addressbook, there is no sign for it in Settings>Privacy>Contacts. It sometimes works (on iPhone 4) and sometimes not (new iPad). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the iPad have iOS6? Does the permission dialog pop up on first address book access?

Comment: Both of them have iOS 6. Regarding the permission dialog, will it really matter? Even if I rejected the permission, it still shall appear in the Settings

Comment: Answer to SVD question, no, it doesn't.

Comment: I think that the answer to my question is right here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6

Comment: @ShatouDev did this solve your problem, because I am having a similar issue and the other SO question didn't solve it for me.  It seems that after re-installs and erases the device will not re-prompt or re-add which is making me think there is some kind of black list, although I haven't been able to find any documentation to that effect.