# Cannot see address book contacts in iPhone

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically Request Access to Contacts in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6)

I'm trying to test out some functionality on my iPhone in which I pull all the address book members and display them in a table. This works fine on the simulator, and I see the mock contacts like "John Appleseed". When I run the code on my iPhone, I only see "Mobile User" which apparently is me.

How do I see all my address book contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6 the user has to give permission to apps to use the contact information.

There are a lot examples of this if you google for it. You could use something like:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);   
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
    // Do whatever you want here.
}
```

Check out this question for more information: 
[Programmatically Request Access to Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6)