# HOWTO set the text of the AddressBookAccessRequest alertView?

Tags: ios

I know that in iOS 6 we should request the access to contacts first like below :
[image: App would like to access your contacts]

But now, I wonder ***how to add detail message in the alert view***, just between the alert-title and two buttons. I did see some-app had done that.

I use [ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) and [ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html), but the previous one's option is reserved as NULL while the later one only accepts a callback block.

I searched a lot, like [another Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6), [iOS 6 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html) and [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html), but failed to make it.

Thanks a lot for any help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NSContactsUsageDescription` key for this purpose.

Add this key to your info.plist and add the Message you want to display as the value.

> **NSContactsUsageDescription**
>
> NSContactsUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the reason that
>   the app accesses the user’s contacts. When the system prompts the user
>   to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the dialog box.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 6.0 and later.

Please check [**InfoPlistKeyReference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) for more keys.