# Custom UIAlertView window text when asking for access to address book contacts

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview, abaddressbook

I have a view controller in my app that needs to access the user's address book to get their contacts.

When the user first lands on the view controller, this is the UIAlertView window that pops up:

[image]

I would like to be able to customize the text that is in the UIAlertView window. I know this is possible because when using an app like [Secret](https://www.secret.ly/), this is what their UIAlertView window looks like when they want access to your address book:

[image]

So, how can I customize the UIAlertView window content when programmatically asking for access to the address book contacts?

Here is the code that I am using so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//Asks for access to Address Book.

ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook =  ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);


ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);


__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {

            // Write your code here...
            // Fetch data from SQLite DB
        }
    });

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(m_addressbook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)

    {
        accessGranted = granted;

        NSLog(@"Has access been granted?: %hhd", accessGranted);
        NSLog(@"Has there been an error? %@", error);


        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;

    NSLog(@"Address book access has been granted.");
}

if (accessGranted) {


    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray
                            *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
```

Comment: Please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161081/howto-set-the-text-of-the-addressbookaccessrequest-alertview

Comment: No need to use any code, just use the `NSContactsUsageDescription` in `info.plist`

Comment: check this [link](http://kevinyavno.com/blog/?p=176) for adding custom message

Comment: `NSContactsUsageDescription` --> Only add message below the title. Is impossible change the text of the title or the option buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the text explaining why you need to access contacts in the application's property list by adding [NSContactsUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW14) key with a string value specifying your explanation.

Comment: Accepted your answer since it was the first one. The only thing I would add is that resetting the location & privacy settings is not enough. I had to do that and delete the app from my iPhone before the change would show. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select yourAppName-info.plist, Add an item to **Information property list**, select **Privacy - Contacts Usage Description** and set the description string. If you test on simulator, go to settings of simulator / general / Reset / Reset Location and Privacy now you'll have the message.