# iphone development: how to handle addressbook permission popup

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

In my app user is asked to be reached to his address book at the first time. Everything is normal if the user gives the permission. However, if the user does not give the permission, when he presses the button to reach the address book after some time, he is never asked again.

Is it possible to ask for the permission to the user each and every time if he tries to open address book from the app?

And one more question: When I dont give the permission, view is still pushed but I see an empty tableview with no contacts as usual. Is it also possible not push addressbook view if the user does not give the permission?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts-in-ios-6/12648938#12648938

Comment: @rckoenes it says if the permission is not given, "Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app." is this the only way? can't I open a new permission dialog?

Comment: Yes that is the only way. Apple does not allow you to open the settings app any more.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks a lot. I will implement with that way