# iOS: Accessing contacts with Why button

Tags: ios, contacts

I see with NSContactsUsageDescription you can setup a custom message for accessing the devices contacts.

I have also seen people now give the user a why button, which then takes them to a long description of why they need to access the contacts.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `NSContactsUsageDescription` string in your plist file, the custom message or description will be automatically shown along with the authorisation popup. You could also create a custom `UIAlertView` which pops up showing details why you need to access the contacts information.

---

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts) a question which shows how to add the authorisation popup.

Comment: Yes, a custom popup would do the job of a more detailed description.