# ABAddressBookSave not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, abaddressbook

I am trying to add contact in device contact list.
The code is working fine in iOS7 but not working in iOS8.
I am getting "didAdd 0" in ios8

```
---
---
---     
ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newPerson, nil);
        BOOL didAdd = ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, nil);

        if(didAdd){

            NSLog(@"didAdd %d",didAdd);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"didAdd %d",didAdd);
        }
```

Comment: add 'CFErrorRef error;' pass '&error' instead of 'nil' then check the value

Comment: Yeah I got this error - The operation couldn’t be completed. (ABAddressBookErrorDomain error 1

Comment: Is that error message for `ABAddressBookAddRecord` or `ABAddressBookSave`? You should retrieve the error objects for both.

Comment: yeah finally I got issue, I follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/12648938/480415 (address book must be granted before access it programmatically)