# iOS 9 - fetched Contacts return with empty Phone Numbers

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, cncontact, cncontactstore

Any ideas why some `CNContacts` come back with EMPTY Phone Numbers?

I keep getting output like this:

```
"phoneNumbers=(not fetched), emailAddresses=(not fetched),"
```

So for example, when I'm fetching Contacts from the Simulator's built-in Contacts App, I get mixed results:
`"John Appleseed"` ***does*** return with its Phone Numbers, but `"Kate Bell"` does ***not*** - even though she clearly has phone numbers.
Its quite strange cause I'm definitely using `CNContactPhoneNumbersKey` in my fetch request.

Here's my code:

```
let fetchKeys = [ CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, 
                  CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName) ]
let contactFetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: fetchKeys)

do { 
   try self.contactsStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(contactFetchRequest) {                     
   fetchedContact, stop in
         print("fetched Contact is: \n\(fetchedContact.description)")
   }
}
```

As I mentioned, the output reveals that *sometimes* the fetched Contact comes back with Phone Numbers, and sometimes it does not. Same for emails: sometimes they're returned, sometimes not.

This happens both in the Simulator and when I run this on my iPhone.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: that might help you  add one more ket in fetchKeys `CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys`

Comment: And I've got crash when trying to check if ([person.emailAddresses count] > 0)

Answer (score 0):

When phone numbers are added in the contacts app, they sometimes miss a label (e.g. "home" or "phone" ...)
If the label is null, the numbers aren't displayed. A workaround would be to explicitly set a default label for the ones missing. A simple example:

```
for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
        guard let phone = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber
            else { continue }

        let phoneLabel = phoneNumber.label == nil ? "DefaultLabel" : phoneNumber.label!

        phoneNumbers.append((phone.stringValue,phoneLabel))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add below lines to info.plist.

```
 <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use</string>
```

And when the time the user will access to contacts in your app for present the alert for permission you should call some method for doing it like :

```
- (void)checkPermissionForCNContacts
{
    switch ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts])
    {
        case CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        {
            [[[CNContactStore alloc] init] requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (granted == YES)
                  [self METHOD_NAME_FOR_OPENING_THE_CONTACT_LIST];
            }];
        }
            break;
        case CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        case CNAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            // Show custom alert
            break;
        case CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
           [self METHOD_NAME_FOR_OPENING_THE_CONTACT_LIST];
            break;
    }
}
```

The method code I took from:
[Programmatically Request Access to Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648244/programmatically-request-access-to-contacts/25956602)

This will ask the user for permissions for Contacts list.

Comment: IMHO: the two suggestions you make are not relevant to the question. Both have to be already-true for the question-er to fetch a contact as described.